# Using Xdebug's debugclient with PHP 7 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug, ubuntu-16.04

I want to debug a PHP script locally using the XDebug debugclient. I don't care about using a remote IDE or anything like that.

Unfortunately, I always this /tmp/xdebug.log

```
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:8083.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
```

I've tried with both the *php-xdebug* package and compiling the latest XDebug 2.4.1 from source and I get the same result.

I've also tried ports ranging from 9000 (default), 9005, 8083, etc.

My **xdebug.ini** looks like this:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=8083
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=mbb
```

This is Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 7.0.8, and Xdebug 2.4.1.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Do you mind using an IDE? Here's good manual for PhpStorm - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+CLI+scripts+with+PhpStorm

Comment: sorry for asking the obvious, is your debugclient listening on the port ? `lsof -i:8083` in a terminal window.

Comment: @GinoPane I'd prefer to stay with the command-line if I can. It'll be easier for the situation I need to debug.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Good thought! I see `debugclie 21763 mark    3u  IPv4 17448139      0t0  TCP *:8083 (LISTEN)` so it does appear to be running.

Answer (score 0):

how do you initiate the debug session?
did you tried to use xdebug_break()?

or maybe the communication to port 8083 is blocked by iptables? (iptables --list)

is there something in /tmp/xdebug.log?

Comment: My understanding, from the Xdebug docs, was that all I had to do was run the debugclient, then run my script. 8083 isn't blocked and the only message in the logfile is what I posted above.